# Dart: Generic which has .fromJson constructor

Tags: json, generics, dart

In Swift I'm used to setting up a `protocol JSONInitializable` which defines an `init?(json: JSON)` meaning that all classes and structs that conform to the protocol are initializable with a JSON object.

Is it true that this isn't possible in Dart (with an `abstract class`) because static methods and factory initializers are not inherited from an abstract class?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm writing a lot of similar methods for API GET requests, which could easily be merged into one, e.g.:

```
static Future<T> get<T extends JSONInitializable>(int id) async {
  final resourceName = T; // TODO: transform to snake case
  final uri = Uri.parse("$kApiHostname/api/$resourceName/$id");

  final response = await _secureGet(uri);
  if (response == null) {
    return null;
  }

  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  final model = T.fromJson(responseJson);

  return model;
}
```

But for that to work I'd need to constrain `T` to a protocol/interface that defines the `.fromJson()` initializer.

Comment: No, that's not possible for static methods and factory initializers.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauerany alternative for this case?. I am also looking for the same.

Comment: I also would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: I'm also wondering how to implement it in a generic method.

Comment: Also looking for this as it could reduce so much redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you want is not available (or planned) in Dart, but there have been discussions on it.

Give this issue a thumbs up: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/356

Answer (score 0):

A MANUAL workaround could be having a map of serializers,deserializers like:

```dart
//Register object 1 in singleton
  JsonMapper.register<MyObject>(JsonObjectMapper(
    (mapper, map) => MyObject.fromJson(map),
    (mapper, instance) => instance.toJson(),
  ));
//Register object 2 in singleton...
...
```

This way you can deserialize and serialize your objects as long as you have them registered without resorting to it's generic type.

The AUTOMATIC (technically code generated) way would be using a package like [simple_json](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_json) to help you workaround this with a little code generation so you don't mess up registering and eliminating mappers.

And the big plus is that the actual code that transforms your objecto from and to JSON is not stored in the object itself but in the generated classes, thus pushing the responsability of serializaition deserailization from the object into the generated code (in a decoupled manner).

Take my advice with a grain of salt as with both approaches you lose static type checking of wether a type has a registered mapper and can be converted.

Answer (score 0):

This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237006/how-to-call-a-named-constructor-from-a-generic-function-in-dart-flutter) might be helpful. you can simply pass your fromJson constructor as a parameter.

Simple steps I followed

1. create an abstract class

   abstract class BaseModel{
   factory BaseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   throw UnimplementedError();
   }
   Map<String, dynamic>? toJson();
   }
2. implement the base class

   @JsonSerializable()
   class ServerStatus implements BaseModel {
   ServerStatus(this.status, this.message);
   String status = '';
   String message = '';

   @override
   factory ServerStatus.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
   _$ServerStatusFromJson(json);

   @override
   Map<String, dynamic>? toJson() => _$ServerStatusToJson(this);
   }
3. In your logic class where you are trying to access your fromJson method

   class CustomHttp {
   CustomHttp(this. Constructor);
   T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) constructor;
   Future<Object?> get(String path) async
   {
   final response = await http.get(this.uri);
   final Map<String, dynamic> parsed = json.decode(response. Body);
   return constructor(parsed);
   }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Dart doesn't support some very important feature for this goal: calls of static methods from generic parameters. E.g. in C++ templates (which not a generics though) you can write code like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T deserialize(MyStream istrm) { return T.deserialize(istrm); }
```

But as it was mentioned in previous answers we can't do the same in dart.

## Solution

Currently in my solutions I use reflection.

Even though dart has builtin [mirrors](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.3.0/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html), but (suddenly) it is not supported in flutter. So we're asked to use [reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) package in flutter instead. Can you feel it? Trying to solve one issue we're bumping into another one. Nevertheless.

Using reflection, you can scan your modules for classes with particular [annotation](https://dart.dev/language/metadata) (e.g. `@my_deserializable`), and then collect for static methods. Note, that you can write your own annotations.

Thus you can build-up a factories cache, smth like `Map<Type, Function(MyStream istrm)> deserializers`. So having such factory at hands you then can use it as follows:

```dart
deserializers[T]!(responseJson);
```