# How to call a named constructor from a generic function in Dart/Flutter

Tags: generics, constructor, dart, flutter

I want to be able to construct an object from inside a generic function. I tried the following:

```
abstract class Interface
{
  Interface.func(int x);
}
class Test implements Interface
{
  Test.func(int x){}
}
T make<T extends Interface>(int x)
{
  // the next line doesn't work
  return T.func(x);
}
```

However, this doesn't work. And I get the following error message: `The method 'func' isn't defined for the class 'Type'`.

**Note**: I cannot use mirrors because I'm using dart with flutter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A variation of Günter Zöchbauer's excellent answer and using the new constructor tearoff feature in Dart 2.15 could be to add an extra parameter to the generic function to provide the constructor (using `Test.new` for a default constructor, if required).

```
T make2<T extends Interface>(int x, T Function(int) constructor)
{
  return constructor(x);
}

make2<Test>(5, Test.func);

// Default constructor
make2<Test>(5, Test.new);
```

The `T Function(int) constructor` parameter is a Function which takes an `int` argument and returns Type `T`.

You could have done this without constructor tear-offs too, but (for me at least) this is just a little too much to parse.

```
make2<Test>(5, (int x) => Test.func(x));
```

This also has the useful attribute that if a developer copies and pastes the function without changing the parameter, they should be alerted by static analysis (since `AnotherTest.func` doesn't return `Test`), rather than only finding out at runtime when the factory list is compared to the types.

```
// ERROR: The argument type 'AnotherTest Function(int)' can't be 
// assigned to the parameter type 'Test Function(int)'
make2<Test>(5, AnotherTest.func);
```

Comment: I'm revisiting my question to see if a different answer should be marked as accepted. I found your answer to be the best solution for my case: I can pass any function, the interface is no longer needed, and can be simplified to this: `make(5, Test.func)` which is amazing. I'm marking your answer as accepted even though it is not an exact solution for the way I happened to frame the question (calling a constructor from a generic function) because it is very good solution.

Answer (score 37):

Dart does not support instantiating from a generic type parameter. It doesn't matter if you want to use a named or default constructor (`T()` also does not work).

There is probably a way to do that on the server, where `dart:mirrors` (reflection) is available (not tried myself yet), but not in Flutter or the browser.

You would need to maintain a map of types to factory functions

```
void main() async {
  final double abc = 1.4;
  int x = abc.toInt();
  print(int.tryParse(abc.toString().split('.')[1]));
//  int y = abc - x;
  final t = make<Test>(5);
  print(t);
}

abstract class Interface {
  Interface.func(int x);
}

class Test implements Interface {
  Test.func(int x) {}
}

/// Add factory functions for every Type and every constructor you want to make available to `make`
final factories = <Type, Function>{Test: (int x) => Test.func(x)};

T make<T extends Interface>(int x) {
  return factories[T](x);
}
```

Comment: It a shame that it's not possible because that would've been super useful.

Comment: I wonder if there is a technical limitation to adding this feature to dart. I don't actually know.

Comment: It's mostly about whether the amount of work and added complexity is worth it. The Dart team is working on making Dart better and this is something that comes up frequently. I guess they'll address it eventually, but currently it seem other features that have better cost/value ratio are being worked on.

Comment: I suspect it's because you can't really do it in Javascript sanely (because of it's mental prototype system), and Dart can be compiled to Javascript.

Comment: @Timmmm it's not related to JS. It's just a limitation of Dart. I think the feature required for that is named "meta classes" and discussed a lot in Dart GitHub issues.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear, let me rephrase: I suspect it is a limitation of Dart *because* it is a limitation of Javascript. Dart supports compile-to-Javascript in a reasonably light way and therefore inherits some of its flaws (for example 64-bit integers).

Comment: @Timmmm I think it understood what you meant, but I'm pretty sure this one is not related to JS limitations. Dart not properly supporting integer when compiled to web actually is caused by JS though (for performance reasons).

Comment: Is this still not allowed? Having a separate factory function seems cumbersome and having developer remember to add the constructor to this function could also be a problem

Comment: No, and I don't think it's on the top of the priority list. That doesn't mean they won't add it. It's just that there is a very long wish list and some other important things are also still missing. Now that Non-nullable is finally out they can take on new tasks.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really useful workaround.

Comment: Funny how there's the Flutter `Fetch data from the internet` tutorial showing the `fromJson` method, and then _various_ threads on failed attempts on calling this on a generic type. I don't get why `<T implements X>` does not guarantee that T has e.g. a `fromJson` declared by `X` (`T.fromJson(...)`).

Answer (score 10):

I haven't seen any good (complete/concrete/non-esoteric!) workaround examples, so here's mine:

Use as follows:

#### main.dart

```dart
void main() {
  final user = Model.fromJson<User>({
    "id": 1,
    "username": "bobuser",
    "name": "Bob",
    "email": "bob@example.com",
  });
  print(user.runtimeType);
  print(user is User); // Unnecessary type check; the result is always 'true'.
  print(user.toJson());
}
```

```bash
dart lib/main.dart
```

```
User
true
{id: 1, username: bobuser, name: Bob, email: bob@example.com}
```

#### models.dart

```dart
abstract class Model {
  /// It's really a shame that in 2022 you can't do something like this:
  // factory Model.fromJson<T extends Model>(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  //   return T.fromJson(json);
  // }

  /// Or even declare an abstract factory that must be implemented:
  // factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);

  // Not DRY, but this works.
  static T fromJson<T extends Model>(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    switch (T) {
      case User:
        /// Why the heck without `as T`, does Dart complain:
        /// "A value of type 'User' can't be returned from the method 'fromJson' because it has a return type of 'T'."
        /// when clearly `User extends Model` and `T extends Model`?
        return User.fromJson(json) as T;
      case Todo:
        return Todo.fromJson(json) as T;
      case Post:
        return Post.fromJson(json) as T;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
}

class User implements Model {
  User({
    required this.id,
    required this.username,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
  });

  final int id;
  final String username;
  final String name;
  final String email;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        id: json["id"],
        username: json["username"],
        name: json["name"],
        email: json["email"],
      );

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "username": username,
    "name": name,
    "email": email,
  };
}

class Todo implements Model {
  Todo({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.title,
    required this.completed,
  });

  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String title;
  final bool completed;

  factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Todo(
        id: json["id"],
        userId: json["userId"],
        title: json["title"],
        completed: json["completed"],
      );

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "userId": userId,
    "title": title,
    "completed": completed,
  };
}

class Post implements Model {
  Post({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.title,
    required this.body,
  });

  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
        id: json["id"],
        userId: json["userId"],
        title: json["title"],
        body: json["body"],
      );

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "userId": userId,
    "title": title,
    "body": body,
  };
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the use case  that I asked the question for. I believe that everyone using dart will have this use case because whether they are writing a mobile or web app, will have to write a deserializer for data coming from the server or the database.

Comment: Thank you for this clear and concrete workaround!  This was exactly what I was looking for as well.  However, I only needed a generic way of calling fromJson() on many objects and was able to easily take it out the Model interface from your example and it still worked great

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call constructors or `static` methods on the type arguments to generics.

Dart generics are not like templates in C++, where the concrete type argument is substituted into the template first to generate a concrete class, and that concrete class then is compiled.  The C++ template approach results in separate compiled versions of the template for each combination of type parameters used by the program. (For example, `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<double>`, `std::vector<std::string>`, etc. are all compiled separately.)  This results in longer compilation times and larger compiled program sizes.  Prior to C++20's constraints and concepts, this meant that C++'s template type arguments essentially used [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), and that typically led to confusing error messages if type substitution failed.

In contrast, Dart generics are compiled once.  Consequently, wherever a Dart generic class or function uses a type argument, the static analyzer must verify that that usage is known to be valid *before* any concrete type is substituted.  For example:

```dart
void printSquare<T>(T x) => print(x * x); // ERROR
```

will not compile in Dart because `operator *` does not exist for every possible value for `T`.  In such a case, `T` would need to be constrained to guarantee that its interface provides `operator *`:

```dart
void printSquare<T extends num>)(T x) => print(x * x); // OK
```

However, **in Dart, constructors and `static` methods are *not* part of the class's interface.** They are not inherited; if a base class has a constructor with a particular signature, there is no guarantee that a derived class provides the same constructor.  Therefore there is no way to constrain a type argument to guarantee that it has a particular constructor or `static` method.  In other words:

```dart
final _registry = <Object?>[];

void registerNewObject<T>() {
  var object = T(); // ERROR
  _registry.add(object);
}
```

cannot work because there is no way to guarantee that every possible `T` has an unnamed constructor that can take no arguments.

Instead, you should have callers pass a *callback* that invokes the constructor or `static` method that you want.  Using a callback is additionally more flexible since callers would not be tied to a specific method name with a specific signature.  For example:

```dart
final _registry = <Object?>[];

void registerNewObject<T>(T Function() newObject) {
  var object = newObject();
  _registry.add(object);
}

class Foo {}

class Bar {
  final String name;

  Bar(this.name);
  Bar.anonymous() : name = '';
}

void main() {
  registerNewObject(Foo.new);
  registerNewObject(Bar.anonymous);
  registerNewObject(() => Bar('Baz'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as of late 2022 the cleanest way I've found to do this is to use an intermediate class that takes a tear away constructor as a parameter and derives the type from it.

**Example for Generic Events:**

This is something I made for inter process communication that only allowed passing strings.

The events are typed, but automatically converted into a string on send and parsed back into objects on receive.

**The Dream**

```
var OnResized = new MessageEvent<Sized>("resized");
```

**The Reality**

```
var OnResized = new MessageEvent("resized", Size.fromJson);
```

It's not as clean as I would like, but ultimately it's only an extra 8 characters.

**Usage**

```
OnResized+=SizeChanged;

void onSizeChanged(Size size) {
  
}
OnResized.Invoke(new Size(399,400));
```

This is where storing the factory pays off. The users of the class are completely oblivious to the inner workings and don't have to worry about typing at all.

**Implementation**

```
typedef T CreateFromJson<T extends ISerializable>(Map<String, dynamic> json);

typedef void MessageHandler<T>(T args);

class MessageEvent<T extends ISerializable> {
  String Name;
  CreateFromJson<T> ReseultParser;

  void _notify(String data) {
    var result = ReseultParser(json.decode(data));
    for (var callback in _callbacks) {
      callback.call(result);
    }
  }

  void Invoke(T data) {
    _sendMessage(Name, json.encode(data.toJson()));
  }

  MessageEvent(this.Name, this.ReseultParser) {
    _addEventListener(Name, this);
  }

  final List<MessageHandler<T>> _callbacks = <MessageHandler<T>>[];
  void Add(MessageHandler<T> callback) {
    _callbacks.add(callback);
  }

  MessageEvent<T> operator +(MessageHandler<T> callback) {
    Add(callback);
    return this;
  }

  static void OnMessage(MessageParams message, dynamic other) {
    _listeners[message.type]?._notify(message.params);
  }

  static _sendMessage(String type, String args) {
    SendMessageProtocall?.call(MessageParams(type: type, params: args));
  }

  static SendProtocall? SendMessageProtocall;

  static final _listeners = <String, MessageEvent>{};
  static void _addEventListener(String type, MessageEvent event) {
    _listeners[type] = event;
  }
}
```