# How to specify a data type for a container class in Dart

Tags: dart, types, subclassing

I am looking for the dart syntax to achieve the following but do not know what the correct terminology is to search for the answer.

```dart
class BaseClass <T extends MyType> {

  List<T> items;

  T getFirstItem() => items.first;
}
```

and then be able to Sub class like this

```dart
class ClassForMyType<MyType> extends BaseClass {
   List<MyType> items;

   MyType getFirstItem() => items.first;
}
```

Where ClassForMyType would extend BaseClass so that I do not have to re-implement the contrived `getFirstItem()` method.

Effectively I want to be able to use it like this:

```dart
ClassForMyType container = ClassForMyType();
MyType item = Mytype();
container.items.add(item);
List<MyType> itemsFromContainer = container.items;
MyType firstItem = container.getFirstItem();
```

I have tried something like this:

```dart
BaseClass<T extends MyType> {
  List<T> items;
  void addItemFromMap(Map map) {
    items.add(T.fromMap(map));
  }
}
```

The above fails on the .fromMap() which does exist on MyType.  In other methods where I access other methods on MyType these appear to work, it seems to have a problem only wiht the named contructor.

Comment: I believe there's no way to use constructors polymorphically in Dart, as simple as that.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if any language I know would allow for something like the code above.

Comment: The first part works - I just needed to properly define the SubClasses with a type.  For the second part I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237006/how-to-call-a-named-constructor-from-a-generic-function-in-dart-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way that would work and look relatively OK would be:

```dart
abstract class BaseClass<T extends MyType> {
  List<T> items;

  // abstract factory method
  T itemFromMap(Map map);
  
  void addItemFromMap(Map map) {
    items.add(itemFromMap(map));
  }

}

class ClassForMyType extends BaseClass<MyType> {
  
  // implementing abstract factory method, delegating call to constructor
  MyType itemFromMap(Map map) => MyType.fromMap(map);

}
```

I agree, a little bit overhead that you should implement factory method in every subclass, but that is the only proper way.

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I'm doing.  I have the addItemFromMap using a "global factories" map as per the answer I found on another question.  So either a factory in every subclass or as this is now. 

I'm really happy with this as it is allowing me to trim a lot of duplicate code and making the interface much more standardised now.