# How to use polymorphism in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I need to use polymorphism in flutter to use it in get data from Restfull API
but it doesn't work.

first I have a base class (Model)

```
 class Model
{
  Model();
   Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) ;
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){}

}
```

then I have derived class (City)

```
class City extends  Model {

  int id;
  String name;
  List<Region> regions;

  City({this.id, this.name, this.regions});

  City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    if (json['regions'] != null) {
      regions = new List<Region>();
      json['regions'].forEach((v) {
        regions.add(new Region.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

and this is a function with getAllModel method

```
class Repository
{
  static Future<List<T>> getAllModel<T extends Model>( apis url) async {
    try {
      bool tk = await Cache.tokenExists();
      if (tk) {
        String token = await Cache.getString(keys.api_token);
        var body = {};
        List<dynamic> data = await Request.callAPI(
            apiName.name(url),
            body,
            method: 'GET', apiToken: token);

        List<T> objs = new List();

        if (data != null) if (data.length > 0) {
          data.forEach((v) {

           T r = Model.fromJson(v) as T;
            objs.add(r);
          });
          return objs;
        }
        return objs;
      }
      return new List();
    } catch (e, stacktrace) {
      print("getAll() | catch exception");
      print(e);
      print(stacktrace);
      return new List();
    }
  }
  
}
```

finally this is a call method

```
static Future<List<City>> getCities() async {
        return Repository.getAllModel(apis.getCities);
  }
```

this is a problem

> type 'Model' is not a subtype of type 'City' in type cast

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.fromJson(v)` will always return a value of the base type, `Model`.

You can't cast this to `T` = `City` here:

```dart
T r = Model.fromJson(v) as T;
```

because Dart can't know how to turn a `Model` into a `City`.

You would want to call “`T.fromJson(v)`”, so to speak, but Dart [doesn't allow us to speak polymorphically about constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237006/how-to-call-a-named-constructor-from-a-generic-function-in-dart-flutter).

I think your best bet might be to pass the relevant `fromJson` function along to `getAllModel`:

```dart
// The type of functions that take a JSON map and return T.
typedef JsonDecoder<T> = T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json);

// Use a provided `fromJson` callback to transform your API results:
Future<List<T>> getAllModel<T extends Model>(String url,
                                             JsonDecoder<T> fromJson) async {
  ...
  T r = fromJson(v);
  ...
}

// And provide it like so:
void myFunction() {
  final cities = await getAllModel<City>("city url", (j) => City.fromJson(j));
}
```

(Somewhat annoyingly, we [can't even write this](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/216):)

```dart
getAllModel<City>("city url", City.fromJson);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

By the way, I recommend looking into [json_serializable](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an aproach i am thinking of taking to render different components returned from a REST api (strapi)

I want to render the components based on type from a response like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "homepage": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "__component": "explore.search",
                "enabled": true,
                "include_articles": true,
                "include_menu_entries": true,
                "include_contributors": true
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "__component": "explore.whats-new",
                "entry_count": 7
            }
        ]
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

I created a base component model like this to capture the common parameters to be extended by each component model later

```
class CmsComponent {
  CmsComponent({
    required this.id,
    required this.component,
  });

  int id;
  String component;

  factory CmsComponent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CmsComponent(
    id: json["id"],
    component: json["__component"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "__component": component,
  };
}
```

then an example of a single component model is

```
class CmsComponentSearch extends CmsComponent{
  CmsComponentSearch({
    required id,
    required component,
    required this.enabled,
    required this.includeArticles,
    required this.includeMenuEntries,
    required this.includeContributors,
  }) : super(id: id, component: component);


  bool enabled;
  bool includeArticles;
  bool includeMenuEntries;
  bool includeContributors;

  factory CmsComponentSearch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CmsComponentSearch(
    id: json["id"],
    component: json["__component"],
    enabled: json["enabled"],
    includeArticles: json["include_articles"],
    includeMenuEntries: json["include_menu_entries"],
    includeContributors: json["include_contributors"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "__component": component,
    "enabled": enabled,
    "include_articles": includeArticles,
    "include_menu_entries": includeMenuEntries,
    "include_contributors": includeContributors,
  };
}
```

then at the top level i can create this model with a method to switch out each components model as needed

```
class CmsExploreHome {
  CmsExploreHome({
    required this.id,
    required this.components,
  });

  int id;
  List<dynamic> components;

  factory CmsExploreHome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CmsExploreHome(
    id: json["id"],
    components: List<dynamic>.from(json["homepage"].map((x) => getCmsComponentModelFromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "homepage": List<dynamic>.from(components.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };

}

getCmsComponentModelFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  switch(json['__component']) {
    case 'explore.search' : return CmsComponentSearch.fromJson(json);
    case 'explore.whats-new' : return CmsComponentWhatsNew.fromJson(json);
    default : return CmsComponent.fromJson(json);
  }
}
```

Thats the data modelling done, then in the UI widget i can do something like this

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
     Text('explore'),
     for (var component in exploreProvider.cmsExploreHome!.components) _RenderComponent(component),
  ],
),
```

and add the following widgets

```
class _RenderComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  const _RenderComponent(this.component, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final CmsComponent component;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(component is CmsComponentSearch) return CmsSearchComponent(component as CmsComponentSearch);
    return Text("${component.component} not implemented");
  }
}
```

and for example

```
class CmsSearchComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  const CmsSearchComponent(this.component, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final CmsComponentSearch component;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Search field");
  }
}
```

That gets the job done, the flutter app can receive dynamic types from the REST api in a list and render them