# Dart: method isn't defined for the type 'Type'

Tags: flutter, dart, types

I need to load data from Firebase into lots of different models in Flutter. I want to have one function that fetches and loads the data (among other things) into any model so I don't end up with lots of duplicate code.

But I can't just call `Type.fromDocumentSnapshot` (of course) and static functions aren't inheritable in dart. So how can I do this?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Item1 {
  // lots of fields here

  const Item1();

  static Item1 fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => Item1();
}

class Item2 {
  const Item2();

  static Item2 fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => Item2();
}

// Item3, Item4, ...

class MyService {
  CollectionReference item1Collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("item1");
  CollectionReference item2Collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("item2");
  // item3Collection, item4Collection, ...

  Future<Item1> getItem1(String id) async =>
      await getItemFromId<Item1>(id, item1Collection);
  Future<Item2> getItem2(String id) async =>
      await getItemFromId<Item2>(id, item2Collection);
  // getItem3, getItem4, ...

  Future<T> getItemFromId<T>(String id, CollectionReference collection) async {
    // do other stuff like error handling, then...
    return T.fromDocumentSnapshot(await collection.doc(id).get()); // error
  }
}
```

Comment: You have `Item1` and `Item2` that have the same interface, why don't use the same Item for both responses or you are implementing every one differently?

Comment: Each one is very different. They only have this one static function in common.

Comment: You can use a Map<Type, Function>: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237006/how-to-call-a-named-constructor-from-a-generic-function-in-dart-flutter

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's how generic works.

You can use **Factory** design pattern.
[Helpful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdFq_JIThqM&ab_channel=Geekific)

Here is a implementation. You have to add `Item` to `ItemFactory` via swith statement. Thus `MyService` class will be close for modification.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

abstract class Item {
  Item fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot);
}

class Item1 implements Item {
  // lots of fields here

  Item1();

  Item fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => Item1();
}

class Item2 implements Item {
  const Item2();

  Item fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => Item2();
}

// Item3, Item4, ...

class ItemFactory {
  static Item createItem(String type) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'item1':
        return Item1();
      case 'item2':
        return Item2();
      //add as many cases as you need
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}

class CollectionReferencefactory {
  static CollectionReference createCollectionReference(String type) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'item1':
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('item1');
      case 'item2':
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('item2');
      //add as many cases as you need
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}

class MyService {

  // you can remove this methods also.
  Future<Item> getItem1(String id) async {
    return await getItemFromId(type: 'item1', id: id);
  }

  Future<Item> getItem2(String id) async {
    return await getItemFromId(type: 'item2', id: id);
  }
//only this method is needed
  Future<Item> getItemFromId({String type, String id}) async {
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
        CollectionReferencefactory.createCollectionReference(type);

    return ItemFactory.createItem(type)
        .fromDocumentSnapshot(await collectionReference.doc(id).get());
  }
}
```

To get an Item

```
 MyService myService = MyService();
 Item item=await myService.getItemFromId(type: 'item1', id: '1');
```

Or

```
MyService myService = MyService();
Item1 item1 = await myService.getItem1('id');
Item2 item2 = await myService.getItem2('id');
```